# SQL server create how to create a new column based on previous row condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a new column, whose values are dependent to the previous index row values, like in the example below:

| Index | ID | AGE | SEX | HireMonth | Tag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 23 | M | 9 | 101 |
| 2 | 102 | 32 | M | 12 | 102 |
| 3 | 103 | 25 | F | 11 | 1 |
| 4 | 104 | 29 | M | 10 | 104 |
| 5 | 105 | 45 | F | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 106 | 21 | M | 7 | 106 |
| 7 | 107 | 56 | F | 6 | 107 |
| 8 | 108 | 12 | M | 4 | 108 |

Here's how I'm creating the `Tag` column :

```
CASE WHEN AGE > 25 AND HireMonth => 9 
     THEN (next row value = 1 AND same row ID ) 
     ELSE ID
END AS Tag
```

Comment: What is the logic for the tag? There doesn't seem to be any pattern I can see.

Comment: The other thing I would offer is that unless this table is a point in time look at a person storing their age is a terrible idea. The data is stale as soon as you save it. You should instead store their birthdate and calculate the age.

Comment: Hi Sean ,Thank you for your attention The actual table is event base on time with 300K record using windows function to partition based on a pattern . I came up with a quick example .I will edit the question to make it closer to actual example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried:

```sql
select [Index], ID, AGE, SEX, HireMonth, 
       CASE WHEN LAG(AGE, 1) OVER (ORDER BY [Index]) > 25 AND LAG(HireMonth, 1) OVER (ORDER BY [Index]) >= 9 
           THEN 1 
           ELSE ID 
           END AS Tag
FROM SOME_TABLE
```

Comment: Your LAG functions are missing  "Over(order by ...)"